# How to use scss variable in css

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I need to change the font size using a variable as prescribed by the author. I am not sure on how to do it. The author claims tha t it ,can be done using css.

This is my css line

```
font-size:var(--sb-font-size:38px);
```

https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-sharebuttons/blob/master/CHANGELOG.MD

Answer (score 1):

You've confusing:

- [SCSS variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) and [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) (the document you link to talks about the latter)
- Setting and using CSS variables

Put the code to set a CSS variable in a ruleset, not in the middle of the code to read a CSS variable.

```css
/* Set a variable */

:root {
  --sb-font-size: 38px;
}


/* Use a variable */

span {
  font-size: var(--sb-font-size);
}
```

```html
<p>Some <span>text</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sass/SCSS variables are all compiled away. This means you would see **just the value** in your **compiled CSS**. By contrast CSS custom properties "variables" are **actually included** in the CSS output.

---

*More information about...*

- [SASS/SCSS Variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables)
- [CSS Custom Properties "Variables"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

---

Usage of CSS custom properties "variables":

```css
:root {
  --sb-font-size: 38px;
}

.your-element {
  font-size: var(--sb-font-size);
}
```

```html
<p class="your-element">Hey</p>
```

Usage of SASS variables:

```
$sb-font-size: 38px;

.your-element {
  font-size: $sb-font-size:
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
:root {
 --sb-font-size: 38px;
}
```

then acces it

```
.test {
  font-size: var(--sb-font-size);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to the existing answers.

Comment: @GertArnold This answer was posted between the other two answers, so it is not a new answer to an old question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well spotted! Nevertheless, it wouldn't hurt anybody to have it deleted now.